# Android Java NDK JNI Passing Object including multiple levels of Object-Arrays to C++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

On **C++** side, I have this:

```
typedef struct OUTER_STRUCT {
char                c1;
char                c2;
MIDDLE_STRUCT       inner[50]   //max.necssary size=50
} OUTER_STRUCT,*OUTER_STRUCT;

typedef struct MIDDLE_STRUCT {
long                l1;
long                l2;
INNER_STRUCT        inner[60]   //max.necssary size=60
} MIDDLE_STRUCT,*MIDDLE_STRUCT;

typedef struct INNER_STRUCT {
double              d1;
double              d2;
} INNER_STRUCT,*INNER_STRUCT;
```

and

```
void PARSE_INTO_BYTE_BUFFER(const OUTER_STRUCT *os, unsigned char *buffer){
...
};
```

On **Java** side, I have this:

```
public class OuterClass {
    char c1;
    char c2;
    ArrayList<MiddleClass> midClassList;
}

public class MiddleClass{
    long l1;
    long l2;
    ArrayList<InnerClass> innerClassList;
}

public class InnerClass{
    double d1;
    double d2;
}
```

My mission is to fill the structure on the Java side, pass it to the equivalent C-structure on C-side, then call the function PARSE_INTO_BYTE_BUFFER() to get the byte array and then pass it back to the Java side. So basically I need something like:

```
public native byte[] getByteArrayFromJNI(OuterClass os);
```

- **Is this realizable?**
- Can anybody tell me what the JNICALL C++ function has to look like?
- If it is not possible, what other approaches would you suggest?
- Do I have to split this into several functions, such as:

  - 1 function for initializing an outer structure instance globally,
  - 1 function for adding a inner struct instance to a middle struct,
  - 1 function to add a middle struct instance, and
  - 1 function to parse the (global) outer structure instance into the byte buffer and return it to Java

  ?

Comment: You probably have a way to determine, in C, the length of returned **buffer**. This might be very important to build the correct Java byte array. Except from that, there is nothing especially tricky in writing all the necessary JNI code, but it will be quite long. Consider using some automation, like [djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), especially if you need to serialize more than one object this way.

Comment: I can't determine the goal from your description.  Are you trying to replicate the Java object tree in C++?  Or replicate the C++ object tree in Java?  Or get the serialized bytes representing the Java objects, and want to use C++ code to do that?  I can tell you right now, traversing a Java object tree using raw JNI calls is a nasty project.  Can you convert the Java to JSON using a Gson or Jackson mapper and then deserialize in C++ using whatever tool of your choice?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want to fill this C-Structure data with the data from the equivalent java structure. After that, I want to use the function PARSE_INTO_BYTE_BUFFER() in C to generate a byte-Array (buffer) and pass this back to the java side.

Comment: While you *can* have C++ traverse the java object tree using JNI calls, it is complex and error-prone.  Can you serialize the Java into JSON using Jackson or Gson, and parse that on the C++ side?  If you can't do that, I would suggest traversing your Java tree in Java code, and create some native "builder" methods that you implement in C++ to construct the corresponding C++ tree.  Anything but having C++ traverse the Java tree using JNI.